# Convergence in distribution and weak convergence implies convergence of expectations

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

I'm preparing myself for the final exam of my graduate Probability Theory course and was stuck with one of the exercises our professor gave us.

Let $x_n, n=1,2,\cdots$, and $X$ be random variables satisfying
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n = X\text{ in distribution.}\end{equation} Let $f_n,n=1,2\cdots,$ and $f$ be bounded and continuous functions on $(-\infty,\infty).$ Suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly.

Prove or disprove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f_n(X_n)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)].$$

Since $f_n$ is bounded and continuous, I can easily show that $\mathbb{E}[f_n(X_k)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f_n(X)]$ (by applying the continuous mapping theorem), but I am not sure how to include the uniform convergence property to finish the proof.

I've looked at other questions, but have not found anything resembling my question except [Uniform convergence in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325956/uniform-convergence-in-distribution), which seems to leave out the part of $f_n \rightarrow f$.

Comment: Uniform convergence gives you the rest (i.e. $\mathbb E f_n(X) \to \mathbb E f(X)$)

Comment: It's as simple as that?

Comment: Simple because uniform convergence is a very strong form of convergence ;)

Comment: Good. Do you want to write it as an answer? Or should I just answer the whole part on my own?

Comment: I reserve the right to be lazy. Feel free to answer this yourself (you'll be able to accept your own answer in 2 days I think - be sure to come back for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|\mathbb{E}f_n(X_n)-\mathbb{E}f(X)|\le \mathbb{E}|f_n(X_n)-f(X)|\le \mathbb{E}[|f_n(X_n)-f(X_n)|+|f(X_n)-f(X)|]\le \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|+\mathbb{E}|f(X_n)-f(X)|\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\rightarrow \infty$$

because $f_n$ converges uniformly. For the second term use a.s. representation and  the dominated convergence theorem (because $f$ is bounded).